# How to change text in Shopify Admin pages?

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to change the text "SKU" to something else on the Admin site, in two places:

1. On the Product Variant column header, when you're looking at the Product in the admin site.
2. On the Variant Options screen, under the Inventory header.

The purpose is to change the name for the Admin user to see something else, it doesn't need to impact the front end site. I already tried modifying the translation in en.default.json but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Its a build in text in the Shopify pages and code.
You can use a Javascript to do it by writing a Chrome/Firefox extension to do it or using a bookmarklet in your address bar.

A bookmraklet is a JS code which is running on the given page when you click it

Here are few samples:
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/100-useful-bookmarklets-for-better-productivity-ultimate-list/